# Remove records from TABLE TYPE PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a **TABLE TYPE** as below.

```
   TYPE custom_type_rec_ IS RECORD(
        pet_name VARCHAR2(30),
        pet_ctg VARCHAR2(60),
        pet_tpy VARCHAR2(100)
    );
   custom_type_ custom_type_rec_;   

   TYPE custom_type_rec_tab_type_ IS TABLE OF custom_type_rec_ INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER; 
   custom_type_rec_tab_  custom_type_rec_tab_type_;

   i_ PLS_INTEGER := 0;
```

and data in above table is as below.

[image]

What I need to achieve is, scan the `pet_ctg` column with values in `pet_tpy` and if found, need to remove that record.

According to above example, I need to keep only 2 records, where **pet_ctg** is  **CTG-Z** and **CTG-M**

How can I achieve this?

I am adding data into table as below.

```
FOR x_ IN get_data LOOP
   custom_type_.pet_name := x_.pet_name;
   custom_type_.pet_ctg := x_.pet_ctg;
   custom_type_.pet_tpy := x_.pet_tpy;

   i_ := i_ + 1;
   custom_type_rec_tab_(i_) := custom_type_;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: You don't have any records where pet_ctg = pet_tpy. Do you mean any records who pet_ctg appears as any pet_tpy, and vie versa? How are you populating the table - it might be easier to not put them in to start with?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, any records who pet_ctg appears as any pet_tpy, and vice versa. I have updated the question with necessary details.

Comment: There's no way to do this without nested loops. It would be more efficient to remove such records in `get_data` (whatever it is)

Comment: @astentx can't remove records from `get_data` because they are needed for other purposes.

Comment: Then I think it would be better to use separate hash table to store values of processed `pet_tpy` (`index by varchar2(...)`) and check presence of `pet_ctg` in that table. It will require additional loop to remove the records that were added into the target table but for which `pet_ctg` appears in the `pet_tpy` for following records. It would be 3n iterations (loop, probe and another loop) instead of n*n

Comment: Why do you want to keep two records; shouldn't the AAA record be removed because its `pet_tpy` value appears as another `pet_ctg` value? Or do you just want to null that `pet_tpy` value - and you delete BBB and DDD because both `pet_ctg` and `pet_tpy` would end up null? What if you had another record with say EEE, CTG-X and CTG-Y - would that be removed, or left with just the `pet_tpy` value of CTG-Y, or something else?

Comment: @AlexPoole Sorry for the confusion. What I need to achieve is, scan the `pet_ctg`  column with values in `pet_tpy`  and if found need to remove that record.

Comment: @Bishan - OK, then that's just a simpler version of the same approach. And pretty much exactly what asterix suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `WHILE` loop to iterate over the associative array and build an index of `tpy` values and then loop a second time and call the `DELETE` method on the appropriate elements of the array:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE custom_type_rec_ IS RECORD(
    pet_name VARCHAR2(30),
    pet_ctg  VARCHAR2(60),
    pet_tpy  VARCHAR2(100)
  );

  TYPE custom_type_rec_tab_type_ IS TABLE OF custom_type_rec_ INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER; 
  TYPE tpy_map_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(100);
  
  tpy_map              tpy_map_type;
  custom_type_rec_tab_ custom_type_rec_tab_type_;
  i_                   BINARY_INTEGER;
  next_i_              BINARY_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  custom_type_rec_tab_(1) := custom_type_rec_('AAA', 'CTG-Z', 'CTG-X');
  custom_type_rec_tab_(3) := custom_type_rec_('BBB', 'CTG-X', 'CTG-N');
  custom_type_rec_tab_(5) := custom_type_rec_('CCC', 'CTG-M', NULL);
  custom_type_rec_tab_(7) := custom_type_rec_('DDD', 'CTG-N', NULL);

  i_ := custom_type_rec_tab_.FIRST;
  WHILE i_ IS NOT NULL LOOP
    IF custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_tpy IS NOT NULL THEN
      tpy_map(custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_tpy) := 1;
    END IF;
    i_ := custom_type_rec_tab_.NEXT(i_);
  END LOOP;
  
  i_ := custom_type_rec_tab_.FIRST;
  WHILE i_ IS NOT NULL LOOP
    next_i_ := custom_type_rec_tab_.NEXT(i_);
    IF tpy_map.EXISTS(custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_ctg) THEN
      custom_type_rec_tab_.DELETE(i_);
    END IF;
    i_ := next_i_;
  END LOOP;
  
  i_ := custom_type_rec_tab_.FIRST;
  WHILE i_ IS NOT NULL LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_name
      || ', ' || custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_ctg
      || ', ' || custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_tpy
    );
    i_ := custom_type_rec_tab_.NEXT(i_);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> AAA, CTG-Z, CTG-X
> CCC, CTG-M,
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=053d1f0eb8e73ad0dc56bba059fbc2a6)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Values are dynamic. So, I can't hard code the values like `NOT IN ('CTG-Z', 'CTG-M')`. Need to scan the `pet_ctg`  column with values in `pet_tpy`  and if found need to remove that record.

Comment: @Bishan Updated. Loop twice, build an associative array on the first loop and then use it to delete items on the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

As @asterix suggested, you can use a separate collection - or rather, two collections - to record the values that are used:

```
DECLARE
...
   TYPE values_tab_type_ IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(100);
   ctg_values_tab_ values_tab_type_;
   tpy_values_tab_ values_tab_type_;
...
BEGIN
...
   i_ := custom_type_rec_tab_.FIRST;
   WHILE i_ IS NOT NULL LOOP
      IF custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_ctg IS NOT NULL
         AND NOT ctg_values_tab_.exists((custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_ctg))
      THEN
         ctg_values_tab_(custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_ctg) := 'X';
      END IF;
      IF custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_tpy IS NOT NULL
         AND NOT tpy_values_tab_.exists((custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_tpy))
      THEN
         tpy_values_tab_(custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_tpy) := 'X';
      END IF;
      i_ := custom_type_rec_tab_.NEXT(i_);
   END LOOP;
...
```

With your example that ends up with `ctg_values_tab_` containing indexes CTG-M, CTG-N, CTG-X and CTG-Z, and `tpy_values_tab_` having CTG-N and CTG-X.

Then you can loop over the records again and either remove those where either value appears in the other list:

```
   i_ := custom_type_rec_tab_.FIRST;
   WHILE i_ IS NOT NULL LOOP
      IF (custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_ctg IS NOT NULL
            AND tpy_values_tab_.exists((custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_ctg))
         OR (custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_tpy IS NOT NULL
            AND ctg_values_tab_.exists((custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_tpy))))
      THEN
         custom_type_rec_tab_.DELETE(i_);
      END IF;
      i_ := custom_type_rec_tab_.NEXT(i_);
   END LOOP;
```

which will only retain the record with CCC, CTG-M and null; or blank the values that appear in the other list, and only delete if both end up null:

```
   i_ := custom_type_rec_tab_.FIRST;
   WHILE i_ IS NOT NULL LOOP
      -- null used pet_ctg values
      IF custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_ctg IS NOT NULL
         AND tpy_values_tab_.exists((custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_ctg))
      THEN
         custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_ctg := null;
      END IF;
      -- null used pet_tpy values
      IF custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_tpy IS NOT NULL
         AND ctg_values_tab_.exists((custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_tpy))
      THEN
         custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_tpy := null;
      END IF;
      -- delete if both values end up null
      IF custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_ctg IS NULL
         AND custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_tpy IS NULL
      THEN
         custom_type_rec_tab_.DELETE(i_);
      END IF;
      i_ := custom_type_rec_tab_.NEXT(i_);
   END LOOP;
```

which retains the record with AAA and CTG-Z and the record with CCC and CTG-M.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5dbdf99c08f9828c58d239b0413d2d2a)

Or some other variation - it isn't entirely clear what you want to happen, for example if you end up with a record that only has `pet_tpy` set.

---

> What I need to achieve is, scan the pet_ctg column with values in pet_tpy and if found, need to remove that record.

Then only track and check that value, halving the checks above:

```
DECLARE
...
   TYPE values_tab_type_ IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(100);
   tpy_values_tab_ values_tab_type_;
...
BEGIN
...
   i_ := custom_type_rec_tab_.FIRST;
   WHILE i_ IS NOT NULL LOOP
      IF custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_tpy IS NOT NULL
         AND NOT tpy_values_tab_.exists((custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_tpy))
      THEN
         tpy_values_tab_(custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_tpy) := 'X';
      END IF;
      i_ := custom_type_rec_tab_.NEXT(i_);
   END LOOP;
...
   i_ := custom_type_rec_tab_.FIRST;
   WHILE i_ IS NOT NULL LOOP
      IF custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_ctg IS NOT NULL
         AND tpy_values_tab_.exists((custom_type_rec_tab_(i_).pet_ctg))
      THEN
         custom_type_rec_tab_.DELETE(i_);
      END IF;
      i_ := custom_type_rec_tab_.NEXT(i_);
   END LOOP;
...
```

which retains the record with AAA, CTG-Z and CTG-X, and the record with CCC and CTG-M.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=333c8d1884d476c5208eb895371affb2)